# What do we call this function? Softmax-like

Tags: terminology

Let $v$ : a $k$-dimensional vector of positive real values.

The function is given by:

$$ f(v)_i = \frac{v_i}{\sum_{j=1}^k v_j}$$

What is this function called?

How does compare to the Softmax function?

I was inspired by the Softmax function, but I thought this keeps the proportions in a way that Softmax doesn't.

Example:

```
v = [1,2,3] 
softmax(v) = [0.09..., 0.24..., 0.6...]
this(v) = [0.16..., 0.33..., 0.5]
```

Comment: Softmax of the logs?

Comment: Normalization of v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\mathcal L^1$ norm of a $k$-dimensional vector is defined as:
$$\Vert v\Vert_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k} |v_i|$$
So as mentioned in the comments, your function normalizes each vector with respect to its $\mathcal L^1$ norm, i.e.
$$\Vert f(v)\Vert_{1}=1,\,\forall v$$